# using 2 Emitter in same componet is not possible

Tags: angular

Im sharing data between components and im using Emitters for that.
i'm render "<app-menu-login"  inside MenuComponent template html, however for LoginComponent  dont do this, cus i dont need render html template from LoginComponent there.

MenuComponent

```
//if i add , then app crash
<app-login (sendFromLogin)="logIn($event)"></app-login>
<app-menu-login (sendFromLogin)="logIn($event)" (sendFromMenuLogin)="Logoff($event)" ></app-menu-login>


@Component({
    selector:'app-menu',
    templateUrl:'./menu.component.html'
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit ,AfterViewInit,OnDestroy {



    constructor( private apiService:CheatService,
        private router:Router,private sharedService:SharedService
        ) 
   {

         
    }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    }


    ngOnInit(): void {
 
    }

     //here is called
    Logoff(event:UserFlag)
    {
      //do sttuf
    }
    
    //mever is called
    logIn(data:UserFlag)
    {
         //do sttuf
    }


}
```

the in my another component

```
MenuLoginComponent:

    <li 
        <a (click)="logout()">Log Out</a>
    </li>

@Component({
 selector:'app-menu-login',
 templateUrl:'./menu-login.component.html',
 styleUrls:['./menu-login.component.css']
})
export class MenuLoginComponent implements OnInit{


    @Input()
    sendFromMenuLogin = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @Output()
    sendData1= new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private apiService:CheatService,
        private router:Router,private sharedService:SharedService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }


    logout()
    {
      this.sendFromMenuLogin.emit(this.sendData1);
    }
```

then in my another component
LoginComponent:

```
<button (click)="login">Login</button>

@Component({
    selector:'app-login',
    templateUrl:'./login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit{


    @Input()
    sendFromLogin = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @Output()
    sendData2 = new EventEmitter<any>();

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
        private router: Router,) {
    

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        

    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    }

    login()
    {
      this.sendFromLogin.emit(this.sendData2);
    }


}
```

Comment: Post the full code. It looks like you have 2 comps, but only 1 is called (app-menu-login)

Comment: Hi i add more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have 2 child components, each one with 1 emitter, but in your MenuComponent, you're only calling the first component, and somehow listening from event emitters from both children. It won't work.
You need something like:

```
<app-login (sendData2)="logIn($event)"></app-menu-login>
<app-menu-login (sendData1)="Logoff($event)" (sendData2)="logIn($event)"></app-menu-login>
```

I'm supposing that the first "login" component is called appLogin and is instantiated in the same main component.

If the main comp call menuLogin as child which call login as child, then you'll have to manually listen for sendData2 in menuLogin template and emit in menuLogin on reception of this event. You can keep the same name the whole chain it works. And don't use sendData1 use explicite names like (login)

Editing after you added new info:

1. First don't put `@Input()` before an event emitter. `@Input()` is to receive data from the parent in the child, while event emitters are to send data from the parent to the child.
2. I would still need the html template code of all comps to understand which component is called by which component.
3. Pay attention to your variable names, the correct syntax is:

In your parent component html code:

```
<app-child 
   (nameOfTheEventEmitterInChild)="functionThatReceiveDataFromChildInParent($event)">
</app-child>
```

In you child ts code:

```
// declare the oupput
@Output() nameOfTheEventEmitterInChild = new EventEmitter<any>();

// send something to it
somethingHappenedAndParentShoudNow(something: any):void {
    this.nameOfTheEventEmitterInChild.emit(something)
}
```

In your parent component ts code.

```
// function that receive the output of the child component
functionThatReceiveDataFromChildInParent(something: any): void {
    console.log(something)
    # do something.
}
```

Remove all the send data emitters in your code, remove the @Input() and replace by @Output() before sendFromMenuLogin and sendFromLogin, change your function in your child component so that they call `this.sendFromMenuLogin.emit()` instead of `this.sendDataN.emit()` and you should be close to a solution

Comment: if i add  <app-login> appc rash

Comment: Hi i add more info, if u can help me